# I need to obtain the product name which unit price is higher

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
Product Name varchar(30),
Unit Price int
)

INSERT INTO Products VALUES
('soap', 40),
('brushteeth', 30)
```

Comment: What happens when there are _three_ products in your table?

Comment: `select * from products order by unit_price desc limit 1`

Comment: If there is more than one row with the same maximal price then you need in: all these rows? only one of them (what precisely)? something else?

Comment: `higher` than what?

Comment: Include the effort you have made to get the higher value, have you got any errors? what have you researched? there are various ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProductName FROM Products
WHERE UnitPrice = (SELECT max(UnitPrice) FROM Products)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT ProductName
FROM Products
WHERE UnitPrice = (
                       SELECT MAX(UnitPrice)
                       FROM Products
                  )
```

This should work. However, I'm pretty sure there is a more optimized way to do that.